# Ball trail effect with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a pong game. I want to add a trail effect when the ball moves. But I couldn't figure out how to do it. This is the CSS of ball.

```
ball: {
            width: 15,
            height: 15,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            borderRadius: 50,
            background: '#C6A62F'
        }
```

I'm controlling the ball's motion in a loop called `function loop()`. When I create another ball inside the function, there is a trail effect but it never ends. How can I prevent from this?

```
function loop() {
        window.pongLoop = setInterval(function () {

            $('<div/>', {id: 'pong-ball'}).css(CSS.ball).appendTo('#pong-game');

            CSS.stick1.top += CONSTS.stick1Speed;
            $('#stick-1').css('top', CSS.stick1.top);

            CSS.stick2.top += CONSTS.stick2Speed;
            $('#stick-2').css('top', CSS.stick2.top);

            CSS.ball.top += CONSTS.ballTopSpeed;
            CSS.ball.left += CONSTS.ballLeftSpeed;

            if ( CSS.stick1.top <= 1) {
                CSS.stick1.top = 1;
            }

            if ( CSS.stick2.top <= 1) {
                CSS.stick2.top = 1;
            }

            if (CSS.stick1.top >= CSS.arena.height - CSS.stick.height) {
                CSS.stick1.top = CSS.arena.height - CSS.stick.height;
            }

            if (CSS.stick2.top >= CSS.arena.height - CSS.stick.height) {
                CSS.stick2.top = CSS.arena.height - CSS.stick.height;
            }

            if (CSS.ball.top <= 0 ||
                CSS.ball.top >= CSS.arena.height - CSS.ball.height) {
                CONSTS.ballTopSpeed = CONSTS.ballTopSpeed * -1;
            }

            $('#pong-ball').css({top: CSS.ball.top,left: CSS.ball.left});

            if (CSS.ball.left <= CSS.stick.width) {
                if (CSS.ball.top > CSS.stick1.top && CSS.ball.top < CSS.stick1.top + CSS.stick.height) {
                    CONSTS.ballLeftSpeed = CONSTS.ballLeftSpeed * -1;
                } else {
                    localStorage.setItem("Player2", JSON.stringify(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Player2")) + 5));
                    $('#score-player2').text(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Player2")));
                    roll();
                }
            }

            if (CSS.ball.left >= CSS.arena.width - CSS.ball.width - CSS.stick.width) {
                if (CSS.ball.top > CSS.stick2.top && CSS.ball.top < CSS.stick2.top + CSS.stick.height) {
                    CONSTS.ballLeftSpeed = CONSTS.ballLeftSpeed * -1;
                } else {
                    localStorage.setItem("Player1", JSON.stringify(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Player1")) + 5));
                    $('#score-player1').text(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Player1")));
                    roll();
                }
            }
        }, CONSTS.gameSpeed);
    }
```